# I have to show $(N^{2^{s-1}}+ I)^2=I$

Tags: linear-algebra

$N$ is non-zero nilpotent matrix that $N \in M_n(D)$ and $char D=2$ . I know that there is a natural number $k$ such that $N^k=0$ and $N^{k-1}\neq 0$. If $s$ is the least integer such that $2^s \geq k$, I have to show $(N^{2^{s-1}}+I)^2=I$.

Comment: If you assume you have a complex matrix and you put $N$ in Jordan normal form, you can reduce to the case of a matrix with ones on two diagonals ; the main one and the other one is $2^{s-1}$ diagonals away from the center (this matrix is $N^{2^{s-1}} + I$), and you want to show it squares to $0$. Have you tried examples and see what kind of pattern emerges?

Comment: You might want to think about this:  for *any* nilpotent matrix $A$, $I + A$ is invertible; indeed $(I + A)^{-1} = I - A + A^2 + \ldots$; the series terminates at $A^k = 0$, $k$ being the smallest such $k$.  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis : I had a feeling too something was not right about this exercise, that's a good remark!

Comment: Yuppers!  Somethings fishy here!  Perhaps zed will chime in with some updates?

Comment: Something strange here? $I$ and $N$ commute, so by the binomial formula $$(N^{2^{s-1}}+I)^2=N^{2^s}+2N^{2^{s-1}}+I.$$ Here the first term is $0$, the second is non-zero nilpotent (unless we are in characteristic two), and the last is $I$. Therefore this is invertible and definitely $\neq0$.

Answer (score 2):

If you assume you have a complex matrix and you put $N$ in Jordan normal form, you can reduce to the case of a matrix with ones on two diagonals ; the main one and the other one is $2^{s-1}$ diagonals away from the center (this matrix is $N^{2^{s-1}} + I$), and you want to show it squares to $0$. (This is because a nilpotent matrix has characteristic polynomial $\lambda^n$, hence all its algebraic eigenvalues are zero.)

In this case the matrix $N^{2^{s-1}} + I$ has characteristic polynomial $(\lambda-1)^n$, so it can't square to zero (because then it would admit an eigenvector $v$ such that $Av = v$ and $0 = A^2v = Av = v$, a contradiction).

Where did you get this problem?